# Android emulator - Galaxy Tab is not working

Tags: android, emulation, galaxy-tab

I have some virtual devices Android 2.2, 4.0.3, Google APIs 2.2... They work fine.

However, about Galaxy Tab API 8 (2.2), when I start it, it just keeps running 50% CPU, and showing up a black window which indicates `0:avd_name` on title bar (note that the port is zero).

Could you please help?

Thanks,

**Edited**

Here is output after I called `emulator`, my device name is `galaxytab8`:

```
[root@pc ~]# emulator @galaxytab8
Could not configure '/dev/hpet' to have a 1024Hz timer. This is not a fatal
error, but for better emulation accuracy type:
'echo 1024 > /proc/sys/dev/hpet/max-user-freq' as root.
emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

For all of other devices, they got same warnings but work fine.

Comment: Can you use `adb shell`? Maybe you can figure out where it is stuck.

Comment: @vhallac, Thanks, I tried your suggestion. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some (unknown) reasons, the emulator can't work with default skin GALAXY Tab. So I changed to some others (e.g: WVGA800), and it worked fine  :-)

My OS: Fedora KDE 14, 64 bit.